# Unable to tighten the cassette lockring properly, how this could be?

Tags: maintenance, cassette

It is an old 12 speed Shimano Deore cassette. I replaced the two smallest sprockets once and worked well for the first time.

After the second replacement that included replacing the 4 smallest sprockets (now also the other 2 were worn), after a single 14 km commuting trip the sprockets went loose. The spacing is suddenly wrong (it looked good when assembled) and I can easily wobble them with fingers:

[image]

I thought the lockring has jumped away but nope, when I removed the wheel I see it in place:

[image]

The sprockets externally looked identical to the ones being replaced, and the cassette initially looked properly assembled with all sprockets sitting from the view and touch in place and tight enough. What it could be the reason why the lockring does not longer hold them properly together?

Comment: In what way is the spacing wrong? One gap smaller than all the others? One larger? New sprockets sitting nicely in a set, but offset from the old ones?  Is the lockring still present but loose?

Comment: @ChrisH the distance between teeth row of the the smallest sprocket and adjacent is now near two times more than between any two others.

Comment: Without having it in front of me I can only guess, but if the lockring has come loose enough to not retain the smallest sprocket it can end up sitting  on top of the hub rather than in the grooves.  tightening the lockring in that position won't help, or not for long, even if the threads engage.  I have one had a lockring loosen.  I think I didn't do it up tight enough

Comment: Can you add a photo?

Comment: @ChrisH I think the photo shows what you have described, as the splines from the FH body are visible below the second smallest sprocket... the two smalls are sandwiched on the end of the hub body but the rest of the sprockets are not being clamped. Remove and reassemble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the small cogs have an integrated spacer, and sometimes they have a separate plastic ring that needs to be added.

I suspect one of the cogs you replaced needed a separate spacer but the new one has an integrated spacer and is already thick enough.

One additional spacer is enough to stop the lock ring engaging properly.

Comment: Simply yes, exactly